# Attempt to read property "id" error when to return http response

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I try to a return from an API, when I try to return API response, this error produce :

> Warning: Attempt to read property "id" on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\samuraiacademy\wp-content\themes\twentyseventeen\template-parts\page\content-page.php on line 3

```
    $vids = [];
    $response = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get(
        'https://developer.dacast.com/v2/vod',
        array(
            'timeout' => 10,
            'headers' => array(
                'X-Format' => 'default'
'X-Api-Key' => '1631861596B5ShPC5xLXu9yjQUqiYfy9KbRUUA6FWr',
            )
        )
    ));

    $result = json_decode($response,true);

    $vids[] = $result;
    foreach($vids[0] as $vid){
        print_r($vid[0]->id);
    }
    
    ?>
```

if I var_dump($vids),

> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["data"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(46) { ["abitrate"]=> int(1000) ["acodec"]=> string(3) "aac" ["ads"]=> NULL ["associated_packages"]=> string(0) "" ["autoplay"]=> bool(false) ["category_id"]=> int(0) ["container"]=> string(6) "mpeg-4" ["countries_id"]=> string(0) "" ["creation_date"]=> string(20) "2021-09-27T08:36:48Z" ["custom_data"]=> NULL ["description"]=> string(7) "testing" ["disk_usage"]=> int(123849301) ["duration"]=> string(8) "00:00:01" ["enable_coupon"]=> bool(false) ["enable_payperview"]=> bool(false) ["enable_subscription"]=> bool(false) ["external_video_page"]=> string(7) "http://" ["filename"]=> string(10) "source.mp4" ["filesize"]=> string(8) "83061017" ["google_analytics"]=> int(0) ["group_id"]=> int(0) ["hds"]=> string(0) "" ["hls"]=> string(0) "" ["id"]=> string(36) "b2916e15-475e-3527-7b9c-3375bfaa2aa1"

Answer (score 0):

Do not need store $result in an array variable
you get ID like this

```
 $results = json_decode($response,true);

    
    foreach($results as $result){
        print_r($result['id']);
    }
```

Comment: it produce Undefined array key "id" error

Comment: I tried with your var_dump but the array is invalid so please edit the message and give the proper print_r array to solve the issue, thank you for your understading.

Comment: I already put the api key for your testing